# How can get Int Type from Swift when using int Type from C?

Tags: c, swift

I am using this code below to define an `int` type for using later in Swift. I am bridging with C and Swift.

```
int testValue = 100;
```

But `testValue` gets cast as `Int32` in Swift. Here is the use case in Swift:

```
print(type(of: testValue)) // prints: Int32
```

It is obvious that I can convert `testValue` to `Int` Type in Swift, but there is a massive difference between `Int32` range with `Int/Int64` range, so the value type of `testValue` should be compatible with `Int` type of Swift.

**So my goal is that I send some kind of `int` type from C that matches the standard `Int` type in Swift. This question/issue should be answered from C part and Swift should receive the wished compatible type to use.**

Comment: So you have an `int` in C that's mapped as `Int32` in Swift. Can you explain what the problem is, without all the screeching?

Comment: Have you read the [Swift Language section on Integers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)? Swift `Int`s are either 32 bit or 64 bit depending on the underlying system (most likely 64 bit on the hardware you're likely to encounter). So, if you're getting an `Int32` from C, there's no harm in casting to an `Int/Int64` because you won't lose precision -- it's not like you're going *down* to a 16 bit `Int` or something like that. Or, do you want to figure out how to create a 64 bit int in C? That's searchable here on SO, although my suspicion is it'll bridge to `Int64`

Comment: @jnpdx: part 1: I did not start explaining about apple cpu's because it is like a most common sense I think, Do we have any purchasable apple device from apple or amazon that use 32 bit for OS? I believe it is now for few years apple makes just 64 bit. How ever that link says my question in other word's as well, "Swift provides its own versions of all fundamental C and Objective-C types, including Int ... " So if you read my question I asking to matching this 2 deferent int Types!

Comment: I did read your question and was just attempting to help. The fact that the hardware has been 64-bit for a while doesn't affect the fact that the *language* still provides a type that switches based on hardware context. I gave suggestions in the second part of my comment.

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr:** change `testValue` to be a `long` instead of an `int`.

On most modern 32-bit platforms:

- C `int` (32 bits) ↔︎ Swift `Int` (32 bits)
- C `long` (64 bits) ↔︎ Swift `Int64` (64 bits)

On most modern 64-bit platforms:

- C `int` (32 bits) ↔︎ Swift `Int32` (32 bits)
- C `long` (64 bits) ↔︎ Swift `Int` (64 bits)

(The above assumes you're working on platforms where `long` is always 64 bits, which is not *necessarily* the case, e.g. current 64-bit Windows systems [LLP64] where `long` is still 32 bits; if so, replace `long` throughout this answer with `long long`.)

---

Even though they share the same name, Swift's `Int` type is not similar to C's `int` type:

- In Swift, `Int` is guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer on the architecture you're compiling for: [32 bits on a 32-bit system, and 64 bits on a 64-bit system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int#overview)
- In C, `int` doesn't have the same requirement: as long as it can hold *16* bits, it is large enough. On some platforms, `int` is 16-bit, on most platforms it is 32-bit, and on some rare platforms, it is 64-bit

When Swift imports API from C, it maintains exact compatibility with the size and types you provide. Because a C `int` on your target is 32 bits, it is imported as `Int32` exactly, not `Int`. There is a reason this has to be the case — imagine this C code:

```
void doSomething(int myValue) { ... }
```

Right now, this would import into Swift as

```
func doSomething(_ myValue: Int32) { ... }
```

so you can pass in any `Int32` value, and it would be valid. However, if it imported to Swift as

```
func doSomething(_ myValue: Int) { ... }
```

on a 64-bit system, you could pass in a value *larger* than 32 bits, and you would get unexpected behavior on the *C* side: you can't fit a 64-bit value into 32 bits, so you would either need to throw some bits away, or the value would be corrupted, or any number of things.

---

There are two possible fixes for this on the C side:

1. If you are *only* compiling for 64-bit platforms, change the type of `testValue` to a `long` instead of an `int`. On a 64-bit platform, this exposes the value to Swift as an `Int`, since `Int` is 64 bits. This will also give you the 64 bits you want in C as well, as you say in a comment
2. If you need to compile for 32-bit platforms (like older Apple Watch platforms) and want `testValue` to be an `Int` there too, you can either change the type of `testValue` to [`NSInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsinteger?language=objc) if you are able to import Foundation, or if not, create a similar C `typedef` which does the same thing and use that instead:

   ```
   #if __LP64__
   typedef long MyInteger;
   #else
   typedef int MyInteger;
   #endif

   // testValue is a long on 64-bit platforms, but an int on 32-bit platforms.
   MyInteger testValue = 100;
   ```

   Then `testValue` will be exposed as an `Int` to Swift on both architecture types.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator That's true in the most general case — on the platforms that OP is working on (and which Swift compiles on), this is not an issue. I'll update the answer to be more explicit, though.